# Linq query syntax is off when selecting into new data transfer obj

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dto

I am fairly new to linq and am having some issues with syntax. I haven't bothered trying to run it, because I can see from all the redlines that the syntax is way off.

Essentially I just want to select from this table into a new DTO. I think if you look at what my code is, you can probably understand what I am trying to do. Here is my linq query.

```
 var SubLoanTypes = _ctx.PrsnVaFhaTypes.Where(p => p.PrsnPk == PersonPk
                        into tmp
                        from sl in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                            select new ReviewerSubLoanTypeDto()
                            {
                                VaFHATypeID = sl.VaFHATypeID,
                                IsActivated = sl.IsActivated
                            }).OrderBy(x => x.VaFHATypeId).ToList();
```

redline over into tmp: into does not exist in the current context.

The question is: how can i fix the syntax for this to work?

I cant find anything as far as resources for something similar to mine.

Comment: You asked no question :)

Comment: Updated the question lol, thank ya @3615 also, interesting name

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq

Comment: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/213/using-c-linq---a-practical-overview/linq-method-syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified and working way to do what I wanted:

```
  var SubLoanTypes = _ctx.PrsnVaFhaTypes.Where(p => p.PrsnPk == PersonPk)
            .Select(sl => new ReviewerSubLoanTypeDto()
            {
                VaFHATypeID = sl.VaFHATypeID,
                IsActivated = sl.IsActivated.Value
            }).OrderBy(x => x.VaFHATypeID).ToList();
```

Thanks